# Steam launch error

Tags: samsung, steam, chromebook

when I try to download steam with Ubuntu on my Samsung ARM it tells me:

```
E: unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
E: unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: unable to locate package libc6:i386
```

I don't know how to fix this but if anyone does please reply.

Answer (score 1):

You're running a Samsung ARM Chromebook? Yeah that's not going to work.

Steam is x86/x86_64 only. As are the vast majority of its games. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, also, do you know if minecraft would work on it?

Comment: Not easily. Java is available (through OpenJDK) but the libraries that ship with MC are again, geared at x86. A Google for "chromebook arm minecraft" shows up a few howtos but it's not a simple ride if you don't understand what you're doing.